# Negative Power of a trigonometric function

Tags: limits, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I was doing a question in which I had to compute the left hand limit of $(\sin X)^{x}$. So in my solution booklet it is given that the left hand limit doesn't exist. When I graphed it on Desmos, the part on the -ve $X$ axis was missing, at least near $0$. Why does this happen? I mean, the sine of a negative number, however small it is should be a negative number, and negative numbers can be raised to exponents of negative numbers too. Then what's the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Anirudh Prabhakaran: What's $(-1/2)^{(-1/2)}$?

Comment: It can be simplified slightly by using $sinx\approx x$ for small $x$.

Comment: @quasi thank you I got it :). But if the question was $(-1/3)^{(-1/3)}$ , wouldn't that be defined though?

Comment: @Anirudh Prabhakaran: Yes, but if $a < 0$, the set of values of $b < 0$ such that $a^b$ is not real has values of $b$ which approach $0$ from the left (e.g., $b = -1/2,-1/4,-1/6,...$).

Comment: @quasi okay yeah I get it now. Thank you!!